# Assign values to array that have multible variables in java

Tags: java

I had created an array of the following class , when I try to assign new values it gives me null

my code as follows

```
public class edge {
 public double w = 0 ;
 public int a = 0 ;
 public int b = 0 ;

}



edge edges[];
edges = new edge[5];
int c = 10 
for ( int i = 0 , i< 5 , i++) { 
  edges[i]=new edge();
  edges[i].a = i;
  edges[i].b = i + 1;
  edges[i].w = i/c ;
}
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Shouldn't you have semicolons in your `for` loop rather than commas?

Comment: When you do `i/c` you're doing integer division, so you'll never get a `double` result that you might be expecting.  Cast one of the operands to `double` first, like `(double)i/c`.

Comment: @JoeC sorry , the question is how can I assign values rather than getting null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems in your code :

**First  :** you should not put your code outside your class like you do
**Secondd:** you have to use the main method to start your program
**Third  :** you should to separate your statement in your loop with `;` and not with `,` your program should look like this :

```
public class Edge {

    public double w = 0;
    public int a = 0;
    public int b = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Edge edges[];
        edges = new Edge[5];
        int c = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            edges[i] = new Edge();
            edges[i].a = i;
            edges[i].b = i + 1;
            edges[i].w = i / c;
        }

    }
}
```

Or you can separate them in differentiate classes like this :

```
public class Cls {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Edge edges[];
        edges = new Edge[5];
        int c = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            edges[i] = new Edge();
            edges[i].a = i;
            edges[i].b = i + 1;
            edges[i].w = i / c;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(edges));
        //Output
       //[edge{w=0.0, a=0, b=1}, edge{w=0.0, a=1, b=2}, edge{w=0.0, a=2, b=3}, edge{w=0.0, a=3, b=4}, edge{w=0.0, a=4, b=5}]
    }
}

class Edge {

    public double w = 0;
    public int a = 0;
    public int b = 0;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "edge{" + "w=" + w + ", a=" + a + ", b=" + b + '}';
    }

}
```

Comment: Actully I am new to java and still learing, the code is part of a bigger code 
for the , and ; I will fix them , by the way I wrote the code in two different classes could this be the problem ?

Comment: I don't think you can have two public classes in the same file.  Maybe just make it a private inner class.

Comment: ooooh thak you @kamoroso94 my bad fix it now

Comment: I tried to do the code as you suggested , but still same problem
public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
 
         edge edges[];
         edges = new edge[5];
         int c = 10;
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             edges[i] = new edge();
             edges[i].a = i;
             edges[i].b = i + 1;
             edges[i].w = i / c;
             
            System.out.println(edges[1].a);
        }

    }
}

class edge {

    public double w = 0;
    public int a = 0;
        public int b = 0;
    }

Comment: what problem you get @laila.almugheer

Comment: While you are at it use `Edge` rather than `edge` for class name

Comment: It is close (0: . You still have some 'edge' in the code like `new edge[5]`. +1 for the answer